# Handling Events for Dynamically created Radio button in JQuery

Tags: asp.net

I have a Jquery code that creates two radio buttons dynamically 'Yes' and 'No' . If I click 'Yes' a textbox should be created dynamically. How can I handle the click/change event of these radio buttons ?

```
    $("#rad").click(function(){
    var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'radio', name:'opt', val:'yes' }).addClass("option1");

    $("#holder").append($ctrl);    
    $("#holder").append("Yes");

    var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'radio', name:'opt', val:'no'}).addClass("option1");
    $("#holder").append($ctrl);   
    $("#holder").append("No");

    });
     $("input[name='opt']").on("change", function () {
      var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name:'text', value:'text'}).addClass("text");
      $("#holder").append($ctrl);
    });
```

But the event doesn't get fired.

Comment: Works for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/dzGuZ/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$("input[name='radio']").on("change", function () {
   alert(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Not sure this works if the radio was added dynamically.